# Entity Framework Core and Lazy loading problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have project in Entity Framework Core 3.1. When I use lazy loading like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<IQContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(...)
```

and I call this:

```
 public async Task<Guid> UpdateAsync(object entity ...)
    {
...
      Type entityType = entity.GetType();
      string primaryKeyName = _dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(entityType).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(x => x.Name).Single();

    }
```

I got this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelExtensions.FindEntityType(...) returned null.
```

But when I remove the `UseLazyLoadingProxies()`, everything works.
Any ideas what can be wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the passed `object entity` is a proxy instance, in which case `GetType()` won't be a registered entity type.

Consider replacing `FindEntityType` with [FindRuntimeEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelextensions.findruntimeentitytype?view=efcore-3.1):

> Gets the entity that maps the given entity class, where the class may be a proxy derived from the actual entity type.

Answer (score 0):

```
package-install: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region Database configuration

    // Database configuration
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));

    #endregion Database configuration
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?